# Dual boot for a windows 8 laptop

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I'm trying to dual boot my laptop with windows 8 and linux. Can someone supply me with instructions of an easy way to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

## Start by downloading Ubuntu:

At first, start by [downloading the latest version of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), be sure to get the right version for you PC, There's two flavors of Ubuntu, the **32-bit** one, **64-bit** one

**64-bit** one can allocate all the RAM if it's **>4GB**, It's also faster compared to 32-bit, however, old processors might not support 64-bit architecture

**32-bit** flavor can't allocate more than **4GB** of ram, so if your computer have more than 4GB of ram, you **shouldn't** install 32-bit one, otherwise, the system will only work with 4GB of ram, the rest is *wasted* and not used

one you download your copy, either burn it to a DVD, or use a tool like [Universial USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to install it using a **USB Flash Drive**

---

## Install Ubuntu:

**MAKE SURE YOU HAVE INSTALLED ALREADY WINDOWS 8 BEFORE YOU PROCEED**

Now, boot up the Ubuntu DVD/Flash Drive, you'll see a screen like this:

[image: 1]

Just wait it for some time to load, then you'll see something like this:

[image: 2]

Choose your language from the left, if you want to Try Ubuntu before installing it, then Click **Try Ubuntu**, and if you want to install **Ubuntu** straightaway, click **Install Ubuntu**, and you'll see something like this:

[image: 3]

I **Highly** recommend you to connect your PC to the Internet and choose to install the Updates, This will ensure you have a bug-free PC as possible, click **Continue**

[image: 4]

In your case, You'll have different options, choose **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows**

[image: 5]

Typically, where are you? Just choose your country and click **Continue**, this is required to set the Time, date, etc.

[image: 6]

Choose your keyboard layout click **Continue**

[image: 7]

Add **Your name** and **Your Computer's name**, Pick up a **username**, Choose a **Password**, Choose login method, and click **Continue**

[image: 8]

Now leave it to complete installing Ubuntu, after it finishes, you'll see something like this:

[image: 9]

Just click OK, Eject the DVD, Reboot your computer, and you'll see something like:

[image: 10]

Inn my case, i don't have Windows installed, however, you'll have another option to boot-up windows, and from here you can choose Whether to boot Ubuntu or Windows 8, Memtest and other options might become handy later